# File serving exclusion error in django urls

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have a problem with my urls.py file in Django which allows me wherever to have access on my admin interface, wherever to load the images. If somebody could have a look over it, thanks in advance !

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^admin/files/(?P<filepath>.*)$', 'my.app.admin.serv_backup_files', name='admin-file-serv'),


    (r'^(?P<restaurant_slug>[^(admin)][a-zA-B-_0-9]+)$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name=os.path.join(settings.G_DOC_ROOT, 'index.html'))),
    (r'^(?P<path>[^(admin)].*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.G_DOC_ROOT}),
)
```

The problem is that with this configuration, I see on the console of the runserver, things like

> "GET /img/field_bg.gif HTTP/1.1" 404

for all the images, that are supposed to be served statically.

I can remove the `[^(admin)]` from the last pattern and the site will be served well, except that it will try to reroute the admin interface to the static file.

Thanks in advance for helping me combining the static file, the subdomainless TemplateViewing and the admin normal access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know python regexes well, but in any other flavor I've ever used, `[^(admin)]` would match a **single** character which is anything except '**(**' OR '**a**' OR '**d**' OR '**m**' OR '**i**' OR '**n**' OR '**)**'. A character class (`[...]`) matches a single character, not a phrase.

If you are trying to NOT match "(admin)", then you can use a negative lookahead like so:

```
^(?P<restaurant_slug>(?!\(admin\))[a-zA-B-_0-9]+)$
```

Or, more likely, you are trying to not match "admin":

```
^(?P<restaurant_slug>(?!admin)[a-zA-B-_0-9]+)$
```

Comment: Now it starts to be funny : The first one, with <restaurant_slug> was actually not a problem, but the second one, with the <path> and the direct serving, yes ! At the end, your suggestion made the static serving regex work fine and I also used it in the first expression, but for whatever reason, the other version was also working there. 
And yes, I made several tests, emptying the cache, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add [`ADMIN_STATIC_PREFIX`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#admin-media-prefix) to your settings and your urls.

Comment: I am actually using Django 1.4 and in this version, this setting is DEPRECATED (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#admin-media-prefix) but it is true that I may be willing to switch to the staticfiles contrib package. For now I was just trying to solve my issue, hoping it would be faster.